# When I add the exchange to my symbols I get a too long code error

Tags: pine-script

I have a screnner that checks several symbols but if I add the exchange (for example Binance) I get the error message Compilation error. Compiled script code is too long: 66337. The limit is 65000

According to you, if I put my lists of symbols in a library and I call this library of symbols, will it solve the problem?

If not, do you have another solution to add the Binance exchange at my symbols and not exceed the limit ?

Here are the symbols before the error :

```
'BTCUSDT'
'ETHUSDT'
'BNBUSDT'
'XRPUSDT'
'ADAUSDT'
'SOLUSDT'
'TRXUSDT'
'DOTUSDT' 
'MATICUSDT'
'AVAXUSDT'
'ATOMUSDT'
'UNIUSDT'
'LTCUSDT'
'LINKUSDT'
'NEARUSDT'
'FTTUSDT'
'BANDUSDT'
'XMRUSDT'
'XLMUSDT'
'BCHUSDT'
'ALGOUSDT'
'FLOWUSDT'
'VETUSDT'
'FILUSDT'
'ICPUSDT'
'APEUSDT'
'EOSUSDT'
'XTZUSDT'
'SANDUSDT'
'QNTUSDT'
'CHZUSDT'
'EGLDUSDT'
'AAVEUSDT'
'THETAUSDT'
'AXSUSDT'
```

Here are the symbols with the exchange and I get the error mentioned above:

```
'BINANCE:BTCUSDT'
'BINANCE:ETHUSDT'
'BINANCE:BNBUSDT'
'BINANCE:XRPUSDT'
'BINANCE:ADAUSDT'
'BINANCE:SOLUSDT'
'BINANCE:TRXUSDT'
'BINANCE:DOTUSDT' 
'BINANCE:MATICUSDT'
'BINANCE:AVAXUSDT'
'BINANCE:ATOMUSDT'
'BINANCE:UNIUSDT'
'BINANCE:LTCUSDT'
'BINANCE:LINKUSDT'
'BINANCE:NEARUSDT'
'BINANCE:FTTUSDT'
'BINANCE:BANDUSDT'
'BINANCE:XMRUSDT'
'BINANCE:XLMUSDT'
'BINANCE:BCHUSDT'
'BINANCE:ALGOUSDT'
'BINANCE:FLOWUSDT'
'BINANCE:VETUSDT'
'BINANCE:FILUSDT'
'BINANCE:ICPUSDT'
'BINANCE:APEUSDT'
'BINANCE:EOSUSDT'
'BINANCE:XTZUSDT'
'BINANCE:SANDUSDT'
'BINANCE:QNTUSDT'
'BINANCE:CHZUSDT'
'BINANCE:EGLDUSDT'
'BINANCE:AAVEUSDT'
'BINANCE:THETAUSDT'
'BINANCE:AXSUSDT'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract some parts of your code / algorithms into separate functions and put them to the library.
The main indicator will be left with only inputs, symbols, security calls and plots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have just 4 functions, I isolated them and tried to put them in the library but I get this error when I try to publish (I changed "indicator" in "library").

    No showcase : Active chart doesn't contain the study you are going to publish

Comment: @QuickSilvain before publishing a library, you must add it to your chart and then pubilsh it

Comment: Thanks I didn't know... when I use a library does it help to shorten my code if it is too long?

Comment: Yes they will help
a separate lib/script should fit in 65k limit. But you can create several amout of libs and import them.

Comment: here the manual for the libraries https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Libraries.html